# Prediction column is not being found in the axis

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I am predicting a specific value using a linear regression model. However, the actual column I want to predict is not "found in the axis"

I have changed the prediction value to a random column and it works fine. But that's not the column I'm after.

Here is the format of the Excel file.

```
     X1     X2     X3      X4   X5  X6   X7  X8     Y1     Y2
0  0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   2  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
1  0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   3  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
2  0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   4  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
3  0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   5  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
4  0.90  563.5  318.5  122.50  7.0   2  0.0   0  20.84  28.28
```

```
data = pd.read_excel("ENB2012_data.xlsx")
print(data.head())
data = data[["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"]]
predict = "Y1"
X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1)) #the error lies on this line.
Y = np.array(data[predict])
```

I'm expecting the output to show predicted values for column Y1

```
Error message: KeyError: "['Y1'] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did this:

```
data = data[["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"]]
```

you removed the column "Y1" from data. That way, you don't have "Y1" anymore in data.
Try doing this:

```
data = pd.read_excel("ENB2012_data.xlsx")
print(data.head())
data = data[["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "Y1"]]
predict = "Y1"
Y = np.array(data[predict])
X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
```